# rails --api doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

So I just installed RoR on my Ubuntu box and I'm trying to start a new API application. I have been scratching my head for the past 3, 4 hours why rails still generates the views/helpers/assets directories. I run the following command

```
rails new my_app --api
```

I'm running the following ruby and rails versions:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.6
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: The API mode is only available from Rails 5 on.

Comment: Oh man, I thought it was v > 4.0. Thanks everyone for quick responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails' API mode [was added in 5.0](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2016/6/30/Rails-5-0-final/). To get it in Rails 4.x, you *should* be able to install the [`rails-api` gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) and use the `rails-api new` generator:

```
gem install rails-api
rails-api new my_app
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be on Rails 5.x+ to use the generator with the `--api` flag